# Checking HTTP Status (Python)

Tags: python

Is there a way to check the HTTP Status Code in the code below, as I have not used the `request` or `urllib` libraries which would allow for this.

```
from pandas.io.excel import read_excel

url = 'http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/statistics/Documents/yieldcurve/uknom05_mdaily.xls'

#check the sheet number, spot: 9/9, short end 7/9
spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=8) #Creates the dataframes
short_end_spot_curve = read_excel(url, sheetname=6)

# do some cleaning, keep NaN for now, as forward fill NaN is not recommended for yield curve
spot_curve.columns = spot_curve.loc['years:']
valid_index = spot_curve.index[4:]
spot_curve = spot_curve.loc[valid_index]
# remove all maturities within 5 years as those are duplicated in short-end file
col_mask = spot_curve.columns.values > 5
spot_curve = spot_curve.iloc[:, col_mask]
#Providing correct names
short_end_spot_curve.columns = short_end_spot_curve.loc['years:']
valid_index = short_end_spot_curve.index[4:]
short_end_spot_curve = short_end_spot_curve.loc[valid_index]

# merge these two, time index are identical
# ==============================================
combined_data = pd.concat([short_end_spot_curve, spot_curve], axis=1, join='outer')
# sort the maturity from short end to long end
combined_data.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)

def filter_func(group):
    return group.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= 50

combined_data = combined_data.groupby(level=0).filter(filter_func)
```

Comment: what's `read_excel`?

Comment: Pandas uses urllib to obtain the excel file and does not seem to store the HTTP response, as far as I can see. Can't you just use requests to download the excel file yourself and then pass it in your first line? Relevant lines: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/2fea54af7699bfeda267d598010a4004b079cd49/pandas/io/excel.py#L185

Comment: @jonnybazookatone Thank you. Using `requests` was the way to go and an easily implementable change.

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas`:
`read_excel` try to use `urllib2.urlopen`(`urllib.request.urlopen` instead in py3x) to open the url and get `.read()` of response immediately without store the http request like:

```
data = urlopen(url).read()
```

Though you need only part of the excel, `pandas` will download the whole excel **each time**. So, I voted @jonnybazookatone.

It's better to store the excel to your local, then you can check the status code and md5 of file first to  verify data integrity or others.

Comment: Thank You. I eventually used `requests` in the end.